# mvvmcross editting a complex object over multiple pages and saving data

Tags: mvvm, mvvmcross

I'm fairly new to mvvmcross and the mvvm model in general. I have been trying to create my own cross platform app for several weeks now and I'm stuck at what would be good practice. I have two main problems, I hope somebody can help me with

**Question 1**:
I have a complex model with many properties, sub items, and sub items in those sub items. Also, many values are automatically calculated based on other values.
I implemented the MvxNavigatingObject everywhere, and all values are correctly notified when changes occured. So far so good.

Now I want to let people use the app to change the values in my model. But because there are so many input fields, I want to divide the data over several pages. But each page has it's own view model of course. That means reloading my large object every time the page changes.
To solve this, I created a DataHolderService, which is loaded as a singleton on all the view models. Then I let my viewmodels change the data in the DataHolderService and I never have to reload the data.

But I wonder, is this good practice? It feels a bit strange to be doing this. Are there other possibilities? Like using the same viewmodel on multiple pages?

**Question 2**

I would like to save my data to the database so it persists between sessions. I have a SQLite database and am able to save the data using a button. But if the user forgets to use the save button and the app is put in the background until the system eventually kills it, the data would be lost.
I therefore added a timer, which periodically saves the data to the database. But I can understand that this isn't very good practice. What would be a good way to save the data back into the database without having the user needing to press a save button? Is there an event/function that will fire before the view model is disposed?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve, however.

1. Is it not better to use a list of questions rather than spreading it over multiple pages?
2. We have created a similar page recently. If your data is shown as a checkbox/radio buttons/spinner etc, we save them immediately when the value has changed. 
   For saving text, we use a 1 second timer that starts when the user starts typing, is reset if the user changes the text within that time and is saved otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I could place everything on a single page. But I think it would improve the user experience if you are able to navigate to multiple pages (using a pivot or a viewpager) to categorize different data into different pages. But as all data effects each other, I'll need to reload all data every time, or as I did now, inject the singleton service with the data.

The saving data idea sounds perfect. This allows for immediately saving everything and prevent the problems that occur when typing text fast.